# Disabling a button on a page when WooCommerce quantity = 0

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, disable-link

I am making a WordPress website and am pretty new to the whole experience.  I am trying to figure out how to disable a 'Register' button on a page when the Product quantity (Woocommerce) is 0.  The button redirects them to a registration page before they can purchase.  Obviously if the quantity is 0 I don't want them to get to that page and I want that button disabled.  I have looked at other examples but frankly I'm lost on what I need to have as far as code and even where to put it.

Please help give me an idea of what I need.  Thanks

Comment: could you please add your code here. And also where that register button displayed ??

Comment: I apologize but I have no code.  I don't even know where the code should go (functions.php?).  I have looked at a number of other answers but have no clue what to take away from it.  The website itself is still just showing a coming soon page